# How to list all files larger than a given argument?

Tags: java, list, file

I wrote this code and can't figure out how to get the `length()` of a file.
I want to list all files that are bigger than 50KB.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File f = new File(".");
    int KB = 1024;
    String[] files = f.list();

    for (String string : files) {
        if (f.length() > 50*KB)
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

Comment: It isn't a typo, I need a String var to print out the file's names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The length() method to check the file size is of File, not String.

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File f = new File(".");
    int KB = 1024;
    File[] allSubFiles = f.listFiles();
    for (File file : allSubFiles) {
        if (file.length() > 50 * KB) {
            System.out.println(file.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`File` has a method [`File#length`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#length()) which gives you the amount of bytes of a file object. You need to divide that number by 1024 to get the amount of kilobytes.

Assuming a given array of files you can do this:

```java
File[] files = getFiles();
for (File f : files) {
    if (f.length() / 1024 > 50) {
        System.out.println(f.getName());
    }
}
```